# Quasi-stationary measure on a finite graph equals stationary measure?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-graphs

Assume the simple random walk $X$ on the graph $G(V,E)$, s.t. $G$ is simple, undirected, finite, connected and let $B \subset V$, s.t. $V\setminus B$ is connected. Let $\sigma_B$ be the quasi-stationary measure for $X$ killed on $B$, and $\mu$ is the stationary measure for the simple random walk on $G \setminus B$.
If $X$ on $G \setminus B$ is aperiodic, then $\sigma_B = \mu$.
Is this true?

Comment: Did you try this for the case where the graph is a line?

Comment: I need it for d-regular expanders. Consider the submarkovian $Q$ on $G \setminus B$ and the left eigenvector $\alpha$ as the right eigenvector $\beta$ for the largest eigenvalue $\rho$ of $Q$. Since $Q$ is symmetric, $\alpha =\beta$. But $\mu(x)=\alpha(x) \beta(x)$ for $x \in V\setminus B$.